# Hide specifics Flat Rates when Free Shipping is available in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In WooCommerce 3, I have these shipping options (settings):

1. Free Shipping: `free_shipping:1` - Minimum order amount is set at `$50`.
2. Normal Shipping `flat_rate:3` - Amount `$5`.
3. Express Shipping `flat_rate:5` - Amount `$10`.

I would like **Express Shipping** option to be always available (shown).

But when **Free shipping** is available (meaning that the customer has more than $50 in the cart) I would like to hide  **Normal Shipping** only.

So when **`Free shipping`** is **NOT** available (and hidden), the available shipping rates will be **Normal Shipping** and Express Shipping.

Is that possible? How can I get this on WooCommerce 3?

Comment: This plugin will make this job easier - https://elextensions.com/plugin/conditionally-hide-woocommerce-shipping-methods-plugin/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [the official WooCommerce snippet code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280610/woocommerce-hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/38281051#38281051), making some light changes, you will be able to hide only your first flat rate when free shippings is available:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'conditionally_hide_shipping_methods', 100, 2 );
function conditionally_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    // HERE yours 2nd flat rate "Express Shipping" (that you never hide) in the array:
    $flat_rates_express = array( 'flat_rate:5', 'flat_rate:12', 'flat_rate:14' );

    $free = $flat2 = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // Updated Here To 
        if ( in_array( $rate->id, $flat_rates_express ) )
            $flat2[ $rate_key ] = $rate;
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id )
            $free[ $rate_key ] = $rate;
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? array_merge( $free, $flat2 ) : $rates;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested on WooCommerce 3 and works.

> **Refresh the shipping caches:** 
>   1) First empty your cart. 
>   2) This code is already saved on your function.php file. 
>   3) Go in a shipping zone settings and disable one "flat rate" *(for example)* and "save". Then re-enable that "flat rate" and "save". **You are done and you can test it.**

Comment: Hello Loic, 

Thank you so much for your help. You don't know how appreciative I am to your kind assistance. :)

It's working perfectly for my Zone 1. However for my Zone 2 and Zone 3 areas, it's only showing Free Shipping but not the Express Shipping options. I believe it's because for each Shipping Zones, each Express Shipping has a different Rate ID. For example, Zone 2's Express Shipping Rate ID is flat_rate:12 and Zone 3's Express Shipping Rate ID is flat_rate:14. 

How do I change the code or my settings so that this will conditional rate will apply to all 3 Zones? 

Thank you!