# WooCommerce: Hide other shipping methods except local pickup when free shipping is available

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I do not want to hide Local Pickup when free shipping is available. Removing local pickup makes no sense, but I cannot figure out how to not remove it using the official code.

```
/**
 * Hide shipping rates when free shipping is available.
 * Updated to support WooCommerce 2.6 Shipping Zones.
 *
 * @param array $rates Array of rates found for the package.
 * @return array
 */
function my_hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates ) {
    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'my_hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 100 );
```

This is my attempt in removing flat_rate1 since that is, for me, the paid option. Again, I want to keep FREE shipping and LOCAL pickup.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_except_local_when_free_is_available', 100 );
function hide_shipping_except_local_when_free_is_available($rates) {
    $free = array();
    foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
        if ('free_shipping' === $rate->method_id) {
            foreach($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
            if ('flat_rate1' === $rate->method_id )
                unset($rates[ $rate_id ]);
        }
            break;
        }
    }
    return !empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide all shipping methods except local pickup and free shipping methods when free shipping is available, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_except_local_when_free_is_available', 100 );
function hide_shipping_except_local_when_free_is_available($rates) {
    $free = $local = array();

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
        } elseif ( 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $local[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? array_merge( $free, $local ) : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related:

- [How to hide free shipping when there is shipping costs in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930400/how-to-hide-free-shipping-when-there-is-shipping-costs-in-woocommerce/62934574#62934574)
- [Hide specifics Flat Rates when Free Shipping is available in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391064/hide-specifics-flat-rates-when-free-shipping-is-available-in-woocommerce-3/46394520#46394520)
- [WooCommerce - Hide other shipping methods when FREE SHIPPING is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280610/woocommerce-hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/38281051#38281051)

Comment: Thank you. After reading your other functions, I understand a lot more.